# Cannot add a new layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer, ggmap

I've got a plot which represents zip codes area of San Francisco.

```
# Download San Francisco zip codes polygons
path="http://moshetoronto.free.fr/blog/sfreal/geo_export_f72cfa08-0728-4a0b-bbcc-1fafc25de0f5.shp"
filename="geo_export_f72cfa08-0728-4a0b-bbcc-1fafc25de0f5.shp"
download.file(path,filename, mode = "wb")
pathfile=paste0(getwd(),"/",filename)

# load the file
getwd()
sfn = readOGR(dsn =pathfile ) %>% spTransform(CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
sfn.f<- sfn %>% fortify

# build the map
mysfn <- ggplot(data = sfn.f, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = id)) +
  geom_polygon(fill="white",alpha=1) +
  geom_path(color = "black",size=0.05,alpha=0.15)
```

[image]

I got a dataframe of fake points :

```
# build the dataframe
myds=data.frame("long"=sample(seq(-122.35,-122.5,0.01),size = 10,replace=FALSE),
                "lat"=sample(seq(37.7,37.80,0.01),size = 10,replace=FALSE))
```

And I just want to map those points on my map:

```
# try to draw a contour plot
mysfn + geom_point( data=myds, aes(x=long,y=lat),colour="red")
```

But it does not work and I got this error message :

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'id' not found

Comment: set the argument `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_point`

Comment: thank you so much it works!!!